# Why can't I select transmission to download torrents?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I've been using transmission for quite a while now for my torrents and up until recently everything has been fine. Now when I click a torrent download link, transmission, or any other torrent program for that matter, will not take the download or even indicate that I selected it at all from the choose program menu.  How do I fix this?  Btw, I'm a complete noob here lol but I love using Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this browser related issue? If so, what browser do you use? Can you elaborate on the tools you use to receive the .torrent file?

Answer (score 1):

Open up Firefox and its preferences window. Go to the "Applications" tab and you should see "magnet" on the list. Click on "Always ask" and if Transmission does not appear as an option then click on "Use other" and navigate to /usr/bin on your file system. Look for "transmission" or "transmission-gtk" and click that.